# Drush commands in migrate do nothing

Tags: drush, migrations

Every time i try to run and drush migrate commands I get the same output on the console. What is this about?

When I run the command locally it lists all available migrations but when I run it on the dev environment it just acts useless. All required modules are enabled and ither users can run these commands on dev.

Local drush version 5.10
Dev drush version 5.11

Any idea why?

```
$ drush @something.dev migrate-status
tput: unknown terminal "unknown"
Execute a drush command. Run `drush help [command]` to view command-specific
help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.

Global options (see `drush topic core-global-options` for the full list):
 -d, --debug                               Display even more information,       
                                           including internal messages.         
 -h, --help                                This help system.                    
 -ia, --interactive                        Force interactive mode for commands  
                                           run on multiple targets (e.g. `drush 
                                           @site1,@site2 cc --ia`).             
 -n, --no                                  Assume 'no' as answer to all         
                                           prompts.                             
 --php=</path/to/file>                     The absolute path to your PHP        
                                           intepreter, if not 'php' in the      
                                           path.                                
 -p, --pipe                                Emit a compact representation of the 
                                           command for scripting.               
 -r <path>, --root=<path>                  Drupal root directory to use         
                                           (default: current directory).        
 -s, --simulate                            Simulate all relevant actions (don't 
                                           actually change the system).         
 -l <http://example.com:8888>,             URI of the drupal site to use (only  
 --uri=<http://example.com:8888>           needed in multisite environments or  
                                           when running on an alternate port).  
 -v, --verbose                             Display extra information about the  
                                           command.                             
 --version                                 Show drush version.                  
 -y, --yes                                 Assume 'yes' as answer to all        
                                           prompts.                             


Core drush commands: (core)
 archive-dump (ard,    Backup your code, files, and database into a single      
 archive-backup, arb)  file.                                                    
 archive-restore       Expand a site archive into a Drupal web site.            
 (arr)                                                                          
 cache-clear (cc)      Clear a specific cache, or all drupal caches.            
 cache-get (cg)        Fetch a cached object and display it.                    
 cache-set (cs)        Cache an object expressed in JSON or var_export()        
                       format.                                                  
 check (ck)            Check common site configuration issues.                  
 core-config (conf,    Edit drushrc, site alias, and Drupal settings.php files. 
 config)                                                                        
 core-cron (cron)      Run all cron hooks in all active modules for specified   
                       site.                                                    
 core-execute (exec,   Execute a shell command. Usually used with a site alias. 
 execute)                                                                       
 core-quick-drupal     Download, install, serve and login to Drupal with        
 (qd)                  minimal configuration and dependencies.                  
 core-requirements     Provides information about things that may be wrong in   
 (status-report, rq)   your Drupal installation, if any.                        
 core-rsync (rsync)    Rsync the Drupal tree to/from another server using ssh.  
 core-status (status,  Provides a birds-eye view of the current Drupal          
 st)                   installation, if any.                                    
 core-topic (topic)    Read detailed documentation on a given topic.            
 drupal-directory      Return path to a given module/theme directory.           
 (dd)                                                                           
 help                  Print this help message. See `drush help help` for more  
                       options.                                                 
 image-flush           Flush all derived images for a given style.              
 php-eval (eval, ev)   Evaluate arbitrary php code after bootstrapping Drupal   
                       (if available).                                          
 php-script (scr)      Run php script(s).                                       
 queue-list            Returns a list of all defined queues                     
 queue-run             Run a specific queue by name                             
 search-index          Index the remaining search items without wiping the      
                       index.                                                   
 search-reindex        Force the search index to be rebuilt.                    
 search-status         Show how many items remain to be indexed out of the      
                       total.                                                   
 self-update           Check to see if there is a newer Drush release           
 (selfupdate)          available.                                               
 shell-alias (sha)     Print all known shell alias records.                     
 site-alias (sa)       Print site alias records for all known site aliases and  
                       local sites.                                             
 site-install (si)     Install Drupal along with modules/themes/configuration   
                       using the specified install profile.                     
 site-reset            Reset a persistently set site.                           
 site-set (use)        Set a site alias to work on that will persist for the    
                       current session.                                         
 site-ssh (ssh)        Connect to a Drupal site's server via SSH for an         
                       interactive session or to run a shell command            
 test-clean            Clean temporary tables and files.                        
 test-run              Run tests. Note that you must use the --uri option.      
 updatedb (updb)       Apply any database updates required (as with running     
                       update.php).                                             
 usage-send (usend)    Send anonymous Drush usage information to statistics     
                       logging site.  Usage statistics contain the Drush        
                       command name and the Drush option names, but no          
                       arguments or option values.                              
 usage-show (ushow)    Show Drush usage information that has been logged but    
                       not sent.  Usage statistics contain the Drush command    
                       name and the Drush option names, but no arguments or     
                       option values.                                           
 variable-delete       Delete a variable.                                       
 (vdel)                                                                         
 variable-get (vget)   Get a list of some or all site variables and values.     
 variable-set (vset)   Set a variable.                                          
 version               Show drush version.                                      
 watchdog-delete       Delete watchdog messages.                                
 (wd-del, wd-delete)                                                            
 watchdog-list         Show available message types and severity levels. A      
 (wd-list)             prompt will ask for a choice to show watchdog messages.  
 watchdog-show         Show watchdog messages.                                  
 (wd-show, ws)                                                                  

CTools commands: (ctools)
 ctools-export (ctex)  Export multiple CTools exportable objects directly to    
                       code.                                                    
 ctools-export-disabl  Disable CTools exportables.                              
 e (cted)                                                                       
 ctools-export-enable  Enable CTools exportables.                               
 (ctee)                                                                         
 ctools-export-info    Show available CTools exportable objects.                
 (ctei)                                                                         
 ctools-export-revert  Revert CTools exportables from changes overridden in the 
 (cter)                database.                                                
 ctools-export-view    View CTools exportable object code output.               
 (ctev)                                                                         

Runserver commands: (runserver)
 runserver (rs)        Runs a lightweight built in http server for development. 

Acquia Purge commands: (acquia_purge)
 ap-diagnosis (apd)    Perform a series of diagnostic self-tests.        
 ap-domains (apdo)     List all domains Acquia Purge will purge against. 
 ap-forget (apf)       Forget all scheduled purges and empty the queue.  
 ap-list (apl)         List all the items that are in the queue.         
 ap-process (appr)     Purge all queued items from the command line.     
 ap-purge (app)        Purge a specified path from your balancers.       

Field commands: (field)
 field-clone           Clone a field and all its instances.                     
 field-create          Create fields and instances. Returns urls for field      
                       editing.                                                 
 field-delete          Delete a field and its instances.                        
 field-info            View information about fields, field_types, and widgets. 
 field-update          Return URL for field editing web page.                   


All commands in migrate: (migrate)
 migrate-analyze       Analyze the source fields for a migration.               
 (maz)                                                                          
 migrate-audit (ma)    View information on problems in a migration.             
 migrate-auto-registe  Register any newly-defined migration classes             
 r (mar)                                                                        
 migrate-deregister    Remove all tracking of a migration                       
 migrate-fields-desti  List the fields available for mapping in a destination.  
 nation (mfd)                                                                   
 migrate-fields-sourc  List the fields available for mapping from a source.     
 e (mfs)                                                                        
 migrate-import (mi)   Perform one or more migration processes                  
 migrate-mappings      View information on all field mappings in a migration.   
 (mm)                                                                           
 migrate-messages      View any messages associated with a migration.           
 (mmsg)                                                                         
 migrate-reset-status  Reset a active migration's status to idle                
 (mrs)                                                                          
 migrate-rollback      Roll back the destination objects from a given migration 
 (mr)                                                                           
 migrate-status (ms)   List all migrations with current status.                 
 migrate-stop (mst)    Stop an active migration operation                       
 migrate-wipe (mw)     Delete all nodes from specified content types.           

 e
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is with your Drush setup on your dev environment and not with Migrate.

Comment: @Alex I work in a team and no one else has this issue - I can seem to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Drush 5.10; upgrading to Drush 6 fixed this issue.